# Advantages of ASP.NET for ecommerce over JSP and PHP

Tags: asp.net, jsp, e-commerce

After looking at many of the major ecommerce sites on the web, I noticed that most are powered by ASP.NET.  I have a background in Java and JSP, and I am interested in knowing why the vast majority of ecommerce sites use ASP.NET over JSP or PHP.  Are there specific advantages to ASP.NET that make it the clear choice for creating an ecommerce website?

Comment: I know asp.net, I can tell you many advanced, but I do not know so good php even if I have programming on php also. So how can I really say you what are the advanced over php - maybe there are more advanced on php that I do not know them. At the end is the computer, and if you are good programmer you can do anything regarding the language.

Comment: Voting to close as "Not Constructive", as it really is asking for opinions. kprobst actually manages a good answer, but it still really amounts to *use what you know*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would disagree on the "majority" part. I don't know what sites you are looking at, but I would imagine Windows-based sites probably don't have a majority market share, although I suppose that's possible. Also I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "e-commerce". Do you mean, say, the Amazon website? B2B solutions?

Both Windows and Linux are stable platforms for large enterprise-class applications. In most cases companies choose technology stacks that reflect their in-house expertise, or go with an OTS (off the shelf) solution provided by a vendor that chose the stack based on the same criteria.

Running an application on Windows is inherently more expensive than Linux - assuming support and maintenance costs are equeal between the two, you still have to pay for licenses. Running an instance of SQL Server accessed by an internet-facing application is also expensive. However, many companies don't necessarily look at those upfront costs as determining whether or not the platform is viable. If you're running a site that handles $100M in revenue per year, $200K of licensing costs is peanuts. Again, generally it comes down to the expertise and experience of the people writing and operating the application.

Also, if you're running a RedHat-based server solution with a support contract with Oracle for the Java bits you're also paying through the nose, even though you're using Open Source software.

So I don't think Java or PHP-based applications have a distinct advantage over .NET-based application or viceversa; rather, pick the technology you know and have experience in. It doesn't matter if you saved a ton of money picking a LAMP stack if your expertise is Java and you're going to end up with an application that is unstable and/or insecure because you didn't know what you were doing.

Comment: My reason for saying "majority" is based on my own findings from large e-commerce sites that I can think of: Barnes & Noble, Walmart, Borders, etc. More B2C type sites. However, if my findings do not represent the majority, then I can accept that.

However, I think of languages in terms of tools; you want to find and pick the best tool for the job. Thinks like wide-spread usage, security, available extensions, etc. come to mind as reasons why one type of language may be better than another. Also, just because a language *can* do something, doesn't make it the *best* at something.

Answer (score 0):

.NET got improved a lot over the last few years. It is no longer a Windows based technology after .NET Core has been released. Instead, it is now a cross-platform open-source framework, which supports cloud architecture, including native Microsoft Azure cloud service, and extensibility with NuGet packages.

Native ASP.NET framework, along with the features listed above, allows one to create powerful e-commerce solutions out of the box. Compare it with, say, PHP, which is useless in this context without external frameworks, such as Laravel or Symfony. For more details, see Virto Commerce platform [here](https://virtocommerce.com/microsoft-ecommerce-platform) and learn how it uses the .NET stack advantages.